# Write bytes to a PLC device

Tags: vb.net, plc, libnodave, ladder-logic

I'm working around a connection between a `PLC` device and my companies `PC`. The `PLC` is the known `Siemens S7-200` and I'm using `vb.NET`. Probably I should use another language but `vb.NET` is the one I'm more comfortable with. To do so, I'm also using  a `PPI` protocol through `COM1` and   `LibNoDave` library to establish the connection.

The program I'm testing has to have `Input 0.0` `On`, so I attached a switch to make it happen. Also I made a `vb console` to read (and write) the state of the `Inputs` and `Outputs` (as the `LED` physical indicators on the device) and also the state of the `Bit memories`:

[image: console]

The console reader (`LEITOR` section - sorry) is working like I intended and all the Q's, I's and M's are correctly lighting up if it is the case.

The problem is, to run the `PLC` program, I also have to lit up `Q 1.1`.
The `Ladder Network` that describes this has the following logical map:

[image: Ladder Network]

I know I have to use the code:

```
Public FDS As libnodave.daveOSserialType             'Serial type
Public DI As libnodave.daveInterface                 'Interface
Public DC As libnodave.daveConnection                'Connection
Public lPPI As Integer = 0                           'Local
Public pPPI As Integer = 2                           'PLC
Public RES As Integer = 0                            'Response
Public REP As Integer = 0                            'Response
Public buf(100) As Byte

Sub Code()
    FDS.rfd = libnodave.setPort("COM1", "9600", AscW("E"))
    DI = New libnodave.daveInterface(FDS, "IF1", lPPI, libnodave.daveProtoPPI, libnodave.daveSpeed93k)
    DI.setTimeout(1000000)
    DC = New libnodave.daveConnection(DI, pPPI, 0, 0)
    RES = DC.connectPLC

    'Write on PLC:
    RES = DC.writeBytes(...
End sub
```

The code is working fine with no errors and an establish connection (until the last `RESponse`).

Here's the problem:
I can lit up the `Output 1.1` (on the device and on the `console`) by doing the following:

```
    RES = DC.writeBytes(libnodave.daveDB, 1, 1500, 16, buf)
```

where

```
    buf = BitConverter.GetBytes(libnodave.daveSwapIed_16(30))
```

by repeating these two steps five more times (another time with `30` again, two more times with `50` and, finally, another two times with `50`).

I'm pretty sure I'm doing something wrong, but there's not a lot of these commands description available online for a guy like me (who's just got started).

Can anyone explain what's going on? And also, How can I lit `Q 1.1` with just one step?

Comment: Is is possible that you're trying to access the PLC from different thread at the same time? Maybe for reading?

Comment: @Marko Juvančič, that's exactly what the problem was.